# Tips about organizing fixtures in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, controller, tdd, fixtures

The most times my tests broke is in the controllers, because I don't know how to properly organize the models in fixtures to keep it easy to maintain. Many times I had to reorganize the fixtures and rewrite the controllers tests.

Does anyone have some tips to help me with this?

*(Some people think we shouldn't write tests for controllers, but I don't think this is a good idea)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely should test your controllers. Personally, my controllers are very slim so the tests themselves are pretty simple.

Your controller tests should not care about the model logic or contents, if they do, you're testing the wrong thing.

Using rspec you could test things like:

```
Model.any_instance.should_receive(:foo)
```

Obviously you need the models to be there so `Model.find(id)` returns something, but you can do this without actually needing a model. Mocking database interaction is one option, using fixtures is another.

Personal preference is to use [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl). It's simple to use and stays out of the way, so in your controller tests you can do:

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, username: "foo", name: "bar")
get :search, username: "foo"
assigns(:user).should == user
```

It doesn't matter how or what is in the model as long as the controller returns the correct thing.